# One to many - reference doc in mongodb

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, asp.net-core

Lets say that I have simple model with one to many references. Both Manufacturer and Car exist in separate collections where Manufacturer should store Car ids.

```
[BsonCollection("Manufacturers")]
public class Manufacturer 
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }     
     
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public List<string> CarIds get; set; }
}

[BsonCollection("Cars")]
public class Car
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm successfully sending the manufacturer data to the repository

```
 await _repository.Create(manufacturer);
```

But at this point, I don't know Car ids that I need to store together with the manufacturer object.
If I first save a list of cars then I would need to retrieve it once again which makes a duplicated round trip to the DB.

Is there another, smarter way to this? I'm aware of the approach with Entity Framework where we provide code first approach and db mapping but with MongoDb I'm not sure what is the best practice with this scenario.

Comment: "the best practice" will depend on your use case. Usually, on mongo db you don't want to have 2 collections. When you do, you will usually duplicate some data on both collections and not have a reference between them. You can also use transactions on newer mongo versions, but the recommendation (from the creators) is not use it.

Comment: Why wouldn't I use separate collections? I don't see any duplication in this case. Manufacturer just contains a list of Car ids in a separate collection.

Comment: As said, it will always depend on your use case. MongoDB has some docs about it https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

Comment: Afaik it's the mongodb client that generates the ID so I'd expect them to be set on your objects after Create() and there's no need for a second request. We're using Guids but you could use `ObjectId.GenerateNewId()` to create the ids.